# Showing missing levels in model matrix

Tags: r

I would like to know if there a way to insert a column into a matrix such that..

```
p1 <- c("a","b","c","e","d","a","c")
p2 <- c("a","b","c","e","e","a","c")

p1mat <- model.matrix(~p1 + 0)
p2mat <- model.matrix(~p2 + 0)
colnames(p1mat) <- gsub("p1","",colnames(p1mat))
colnames(p2mat) <- gsub("p2","",colnames(p2mat))
```

this would give me for `p1mat`

```
  a b c d e
1 1 0 0 0 0
2 0 1 0 0 0
3 0 0 1 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 1
5 0 0 0 1 0
6 1 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 1 0 0
```

and for `p2mat`

```
  a b c e
1 1 0 0 0
2 0 1 0 0
3 0 0 1 0
4 0 0 0 1
5 0 0 0 1
6 1 0 0 0
7 0 0 1 0
```

My question is, is there a way to sneak in a column vector `d` consisting of only zeros into the matrix `p2mat`? such that

```
   d
   0
   0
   0
   0
   0
   0
   0
```

and the vector is automatically ordered and placed between columns `c` and `e` resulting in to following matrix for `p2mat`

```
  a b c d e
1 1 0 0 0 0
2 0 1 0 0 0
3 0 0 1 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 1
5 0 0 0 0 1
6 1 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 1 0 0
```

Basically I want matrix `p2mat` to look into every column in `p1mat` to create an identical size matrix and to keep track of the data via dummy matrices.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you only checking for column presence in one direction? Or are you looking to make sure both matrices have identical sets of columns. If the latter, you may want to review the `match_matrices` function for different test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function takes 2 matrices, and compares their dimensions. If their dimensions differ, it **inserts a new column of zeros into the matrix with fewer columns**, at the exact column position that is lacking. It thus produces a new matrix with the same dimensions as the other.

```
match_matrices <- function(matrix1, matrix2) {
    if(ncol(matrix1) != ncol(matrix2)) {
    get_cols <- function(x) { l <- list(); for(i in 1:ncol(x)) { l[i] <- list(as.numeric(x[,i])) };  return(l) }
    k <- get_cols(matrix2)
    odd_one_out <- setdiff(colnames(matrix1), colnames(matrix2))
    insert_at <- which(colnames(matrix1) == odd_one_out)
    res <- t(do.call('rbind', append(k, list(rep(0, nrow(matrix2))), insert_at-1)))
    colnames(res) <- colnames(matrix1)
    }
    return(res)
    }
```

**Using your matrices:**

```
match_matrices(p1mat, p2mat)
```

[image]

Comment: If this is the approach you're going to be taking, you're going to be better off actually matching names of each of the matrices.

Comment: Start with `p1 <- c("a","b","c","e","d","a","c"); p2 <-c("a","b","x","e","e","a","x")` and continue with the OP's steps, then try this function.

Answer (score 4):

You can `factor` both your inputs, making sure they both have the same levels. Then `model.matrix` should work as you expected.

Example:

```
p1 <- c("a","b","c","e","d","a","c")
p2 <- c("a","b","c","e","e","a","c")

levs <- sort(unique(c(p1, p2)))
f1 <- factor(p1, levs)
f2 <- factor(p2, levs)

model.matrix(~f1 + 0)
#   f1a f1b f1c f1d f1e
# 1   1   0   0   0   0
# 2   0   1   0   0   0
# 3   0   0   1   0   0
# 4   0   0   0   0   1
# 5   0   0   0   1   0
# 6   1   0   0   0   0
# 7   0   0   1   0   0
# attr(,"assign")
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
# attr(,"contrasts")
# attr(,"contrasts")$f1
# [1] "contr.treatment"

model.matrix(~f2 + 0)
#   f2a f2b f2c f2d f2e
# 1   1   0   0   0   0
# 2   0   1   0   0   0
# 3   0   0   1   0   0
# 4   0   0   0   0   1
# 5   0   0   0   0   1
# 6   1   0   0   0   0
# 7   0   0   1   0   0
# attr(,"assign")
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
# attr(,"contrasts")
# attr(,"contrasts")$f2
# [1] "contr.treatment"
```

---

If you're really looking to write a function, you might want to look at something like the following:

```
myfun <- function(..., overwrite = FALSE) {
  l <- setNames(list(...), sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse))
  cols <- sort(unique(unlist(lapply(l, colnames), use.names = FALSE)))
  out <- lapply(l, function(x) {
    cols_x <- c(colnames(x), setdiff(cols, colnames(x)))
    temp <- `colnames<-`(x[, match(cols, colnames(x))], cols_x)[, cols]
    replace(temp, is.na(temp), 0)
  })
  if (isTRUE(overwrite)) list2env(out, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  out
}
```

This will take any number of items as inputs, compare the columns in all of them, and add missing columns where necessary. The output is stored as a `list`, which is a convenient structure to keep if you want to continue doing similar operations on all of the matrices. If you want to overwrite the original object, then you can change the "`overwrite`" argument to `TRUE`.

Here's some more sample data to work with.

```
set.seed(1)
p1 <- c("a","b","c","e","d","a","c"); p2 <-c("a","b","x","e","e","a","x")
p3 <- sample(c(cols, "z"), 7, TRUE)

p1mat <- model.matrix(~p1 + 0)
p2mat <- model.matrix(~p2 + 0)
p3mat <- model.matrix(~p3 + 0)
colnames(p1mat) <- gsub("p1","",colnames(p1mat))
colnames(p2mat) <- gsub("p2","",colnames(p2mat))
colnames(p3mat) <- gsub("p3","",colnames(p3mat))
```

Try the function out:

```
myfun(p1mat, p2mat)
myfun(p2mat, p1mat)
myfun(p3mat, p1mat)
myfun(p3mat, p1mat, p2mat)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! this was exactly what I was looking for.